# Android layout:weight doesn't work even when width/height are 0

Tags: android, android-layout

FrameLayout's layout_weight is 0.13 but it looks like much bigger than it. Why? A lot of reccomendations are android:layout_height="0dp", but it doesn't help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/background" android:weightSum="1">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp" android:background="@drawable/bar_background" android:layout_weight="0.13">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/header"
                android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_gravity="center" android:textSize="@dimen/header_size"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/header_margin_top" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <EditText
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:id="@+id/textEdit"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" android:layout_gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/separator"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
        <ListView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/listView" android:layout_gravity="center" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:scrollingCache="false" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, looks like it's IntelliJ IDEA's preview bug. All is good on the device. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* it might be because none of the FrameLayout's siblings have a weight. Try adding a weight (probably .87) to your inner LinearLayout and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Did you also set the inner LinearLayout's height to 0dp when you did this?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your layout and after setting a weight of 0.87 and a layout_height of 0dp to the sibling LinearLayout it works fine to me. Maybe the dimensions you are setting to the inner TextView in the FrameLayout are too large?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:textSize="@dimen/header_size"
```

I think because of this is too large so it force you FrameLayout to be larger than it should be

Comment: Unset margin and textSize - text became very small, but FrameLayout's height didn't change.